# Trying to get the sum, but doesn't seem to be working

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm learning python and was working on this question and can't seem to get it to work. When this code is executed I get the numbers 1 thru 8 on separate lines. How can I to just print the count of 8?

```
honor_roll_count = 0
student_grades = ["A", "C", "B", "B", "C", "A", "F", "B", "B", "B", "C", "A"]
for grade in student_grades:
    if grade in "AB":
        honor_roll_count = honor_roll_count + 1
        print honor_roll_count
```

Comment: print the value after the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your `print` is indented, which means it's inside the `if` inside the `for` loop, so it happens for every "A" or "B".  You want it after the loop.

```
for grade in student_grades:
    if grade in "AB":
        honor_roll_count = honor_roll_count + 1
print honor_roll_count
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the `print` statement to the left, two indentation levels:

```
for grade in student_grades:
    if grade in "AB":
        honor_roll_count = honor_roll_count + 1
print honor_roll_count
```

Now it'll be executed *after* the loop has *completed*, instead of for every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
honor_roll_count = 0
student_grades = ["A", "C", "B", "B", "C", "A", "F", "B", "B", "B", "C", "A"]
for grade in student_grades:
    if grade in "AB":
        honor_roll_count += 1
print honor_roll_count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
honor_count = student_grades.count("A") + student_grades.count("B")
```

OR

```
honor_count = sum([student_grades.count(grade) for grade in "AB"])
```